# Oracle XE not seeing tables with names longer than 14 chars

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc, oracle-xe, tns

I have an Oracle XE database link to a MySQL 5.7 instance. The link is working fine as I am able to do lookups like:

```
select count(*) from "wp_mal_mast"@MYSQl1;
```

However, when I try to do this for tables with a name greater than 14 characters, it fails with an error:

```
select count(*) from "123456789012345"@MYSQL1;

ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSQL1)))
```

But, if I select anything up to 14 chars, even non-existing, I get a normal response:

```
select count(*) from "12345678901234"@MYSQL1;

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.7.19-log]Table 'blah.12345678901234' doesn't exist {42S02,NativeErr = 1146}
```

Here is my init[SID].

```
initMYSQL1.ora
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=MYSQL1
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=OFF
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
set ODBCINI=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/odbc.ini
```